# Do Azure Container instance running on Linux or Windows host?

Tags: azure-container-instances

My question may sounds weird but i have a scenario which may be explained if you could confirm. Basically i experienced issue with Linux ACI that i do not have when i run my container either locally (on Windows 10 with wsl2) or on Linux VM.

So i try to detect the host OS using command `uname -a`

Step 1: On my Linux container running on my Windows10 with wsl2, i get:

```
Linux 1a67c6f4eb2d 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Step 2: On my Linux container running on my ubuntu VM i get:

```
Linux b06ba4a9f68b 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Step 3: on my Linux container running on Azure Container instance i get:

```
Linux SandboxHost-638071330812554054 5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Mar 7 17:36:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When it reads **microsoft-standard**, does it mean that ACI is running on Windows Operating system ? That may explain my issue that i do not get on step 2 and step 1.

Do you know if it is possible to instantiate an ACI on Linux host instead ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created both Windows and Linux based containers and got the host OS as windows only.

**Windows based container: **
[image]
**Linux based container:**
[image]
Based on above repro we can say that the host OS should be windows for all the container instances.
So, we can conclude that

> **When it reads Microsoft-standard, does it mean that ACI is running on Windows Operating system?**

– Yes, the host OS should be Windows.

> **Do you know if it is possible to instantiate an ACI on Linux host instead?**

– As per my knowledge, not supported as of today.